# How do I search through multiple domain controller's security logs and limited dates in Powershell?

Tags: loops, powershell, formatting

Good Morning, Good Afternoon, Good Evening, or Goodnight!

I'm trying to undertake a project for my internship. The purpose of the script is how to search for lockout events for a specific user within certain (given) time constraints throughout the different security logs.

```
 $ComputerName =     
 [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().FindDomainController().Name

 $EventList = Get-Eventlog –ComputerName $ComputerName -LogName Security 
 -InstanceID 4740 -Message *Username*

 $EventList | Format-List -Property TimeGenerated,Message
```

So I'm curious on how to use the date class to output error messages from a specific date. For example, if I want to only view error messages from 5/05/2014 to 5/20/2014. Also as far as how to loop through each of the Domain Controllers on our network. I figure it'd be easy to just set up some type of loop construct for that. (Once I know the proper syntax)

So there's my code initially. If you would like a similiar code for your own jolly kicks to find whatever type of error you'd like, then take this.

```
 $ComputerName = "REPLACEWITHYOURCOMPUTERNAME"

 $EventList = Get-Eventlog –ComputerName $ComputerName -LogName Security -Message      *REPLACEWITHYOURUSERNAME*

 $EventList | Format-List -Property TimeGenerated,Message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for 2 days ago max:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After ((Get-Date).AddDays(-2))
```

To search yesterday only:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After ((Get-Date).AddDays(-2)) -Before ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1))
```

I think you should grasp the idea by now. Of course, for a final script to be functional you would have to wrap it around in parameters and so on.

Edit: You also asked how to create a loop.

Example:

```
$ComputerList = Get-Content ComputerList.txt
foreach ($Computer in $Computerlist) { 
Get-EventLog -Logname Security -Computername $Computer 

Write-host "$Computer has been checked" 
}
```

As a side note for several-DC environment this is going to be nasty network-killer script. Parsing Event logs remotely is generally a bad idea. Instead, think about Invoke-Command to launch the queries and wait until DCs send you the output. This way they are executed locally and all you receive is an output. Much faster in general in conjunction with Start-Job for example.